# html form to PDF issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

Issue: Word is wrapping when I am typing in the html page. But, after downloading the form as PDF, it is not showing the word as wrapped. Please see the screenshot below:

[Before downloading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AOfR.png)

[After downloading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0Bmc.png)

```js
// download contents of the page
document.getElementById("download").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const formBox = document.getElementById("formBox");

  var opt = {
    margin: 0,
    filename: "caseFile" + request + ".pdf",
    html2canvas: {
      scale: 2
    },
    jsPDF: {
      unit: 'in',
      format: 'letter',
      orientation: 'portrait'
    }
  };
  html2pdf().from(formBox).set(opt).save();

})
```

```html
<form id="formBox">

  <table id="caseInfo">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Case Info</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Date of Offense</td>
      <td>
        <input type="date" id="dateOffense">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Time of Offense</td>
      <td><input type="time" id="timeOffense"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Location of Offense</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="locationOffense"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>City</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="caseCity"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Zip</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="caseZip"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Type of Offense</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="typeOffense"></td>
    </tr>


  </table>
  <br>

  <div class="row">

    <table class="column" id="caseAuthorizedBy">
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Case Authorized By</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Consent</td>
        <td>
          <input type="radio" name="search" id="consent">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Search Warrant</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="search" id="searchWarrant"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Deceased</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="search" id="Deceased"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Other(Specify)</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="search" id="otherSearch"></td>
      </tr>

    </table>


    <br>

    <table class="column" id="custodyInformation">
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Custody Info</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>In-Custody</td>
        <td> <input type="radio" name="custody" id="inCustody"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Not In-Custody</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="custody" id="notInCustody"></td>
      </tr>

    </table>


  </div>

  <br><br>

  <div id="root0"></div>


  <!-- <hr> -->
  <br><br>

  <div id="analysisDiv">
    <table id="analysisTable">
      <tr>
        <th colspan="1">Analysis</th>
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <td><textarea id="analysis" rows="15" cols="20" wrap="hard" name="text" /></textarea>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>

  <br>

</form>

<!--PDF download button-->
<div class="downloadButton">
  <button class="button-15" id="download">Download PDF</button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2pdf.js/0.10.1/html2pdf.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I need help with this. I have tried many examples I found online. But couldn't find anything helpful. I am new to JavaScript, so I don't know any effective way of doing this. If my javascript is incorrect or not an effective way of doing it feel free to provide new code or way of doing this. I am totally lost. Help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please, add the info about the libraries being used in your question. I guess `html2pdf()` is not a pure javascript function.. Is [this](https://ekoopmans.github.io/html2pdf.js/) library involved?

Comment: could you possibly include the `html2pdf` function in your code as well, so we can try it ourselves? I tried extracting your code but the download wont work unless I include the `html2pdf`

Comment: idk why it's not working. Updated the code and reposted it. Worked on my VS Code. :( I tried some other ways, but I couldn't make the button to download the content of HTML.